# UTM survey coordinates not coming in correctly

Tags: coordinate-system, utm, land-survey

I am a QGIS noob but semi experienced in Arc and other GIS softwares. I am trying to bring in points staked out in NAD83 UTM Zone 15N but they won't come in right on QGIS. I've changed the map CRS to the proper one (EPSG: 32615), changed map measurements to Ft (if that matters) and nothing I've tried will get them to show up right. I've tried both bringing them in as Northing/Easting to the proper UTM zone, and using the lat/long on both NAD83 and WGS84. They should be in Iowa, not Siberia. Below is a sample of the data

| Name | Easting | Northing | Elevation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 905750.1 | 14842386.65 | 1157.493 |
| 101 | 905791.1 | 14842337.31 | 1154.553 |
| 102 | 905806.8 | 14842292.62 | 1154.552 |
| 103 | 905820.4 | 14842246.59 | 1154.521 |

Comment: Please post your coordinates as text, not a photo. Posting it as text will make it easier to check things.

Comment: Those coordinates aren't UTM, the northings are too big, they should only have 7 digits (excluding the decimals).  Example Easting, Northing in UTM 15N for Des Moines Iowa is 449182, 4604577.  Also note that NAD83 UTM Zone 15N is EPSG:26915 not EPSG:32615 (that's WGS84 UTM Zone 15N) but that won't make much difference given how way off your coordinates are.

Comment: If the easting/northing values are really in US survey feet, try using the NAD 1983 BLM zone 15, EPSG:32165, instead.

Comment: @mkennedy this was it! I didnt think they would give me survey feet. Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer with that information!